# How can I plot multiple line graphs from multiple data files on the same graph?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot multiple lines on a single graph, where the data for each line is in a separate data file. Data is a date/time and a real number.
I can plot a single line/data file, but cannot get multiple lines/data files to plot correctly (sharing the same axes).

I have several data files containing date/time and value lines, like this:

output0.tsv:

```
2023-10-13 08:05:22 3.77362878455463
2023-10-13 08:16:38 3.77371398500197
2023-10-13 08:27:54 3.77415538319968
2023-10-13 08:36:29 3.77337830143226
2023-10-13 08:46:20 3.7721485759286
...
```

output1.tsv:

```
2023-10-13 08:06:12 9.58516483516484
2023-10-13 08:17:28 9.58519607843137
2023-10-13 08:28:44 9.5859382655561
2023-10-13 08:37:19 9.58436979727744
2023-10-13 08:47:09 9.58482994861757
...
```

I want to plot both of these on the same graph, so I use these gnuplot commands:

```
set terminal qt size 1300,600
set grid
set mxtics 4
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set xdata time
set datafile sep ' '
set xtics format "%F %R" rotate
plot "output1.tsv" using 1:3 title "computer A" with lines,\
  "output0.tsv" using 1:3 title "computer B" with lines
```

However this shows a graph with two horizontal lines (seemingly showing the first value of each file as a constant across the whole graph). The titles are correct.

If I show just a single data file with:

```
set terminal qt size 1300,600
set grid
set mxtics 4
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set xdata time
set datafile sep ' '
set xtics format "%F %R" rotate
plot "output1.tsv" using 1:3 title "computer A" with lines
```

Then this works as expected, showing the line graph with values varying across the time period required (and title).

What am I doing wrong in my attempt to plot several data files' values as separate lines on the same graph? (Sharing the same axes - X is date/time, Y is value).

Note: date/times are not the same across the two files - the data represent metrics recorded from a set of computers over a time period, with each computer's recordings in its own file, and the set looped over with each computer recorded sequentially. So I record computer A, then B, then A again, then B again, etc. Each recording takes a few seconds.

I'm using gnuplot 5.4 patchlevel 2 on a modern Ubuntu Linux variant.

Comment: eyeballing your data y autoscale will be on 10 when both datasets are plotted and they **are** the same numbers to 3 sig fig. The most you can hope for is a line that is two or three pixels higher at one end assuming a 1k display height. Change "with lines" to "with linespoints" and that should show you if your data points are being plotted.

Comment: Thank you Martin, however the above datasets are small sections - the actual files have around 60 measurements and when plotted singly show a definite non-straight line trending down - changing to 'with linespoints' still shows horizontal lines with no obvious deviation from a single value (but now with point markers).

Comment: What are the full ranges of y-values in your complete data files?

Comment: Hi, thank you, for the two data files in question:
min 3.76165073403892, mean 3.7655076188005, max 3.77415538319968
and 
min 9.5530639221981, mean 9.56624671935537, max 9.58745971286258
(see below)

Comment: Question answered? Problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

As @MartinBrown already pointed out in the comments: It looks like the changes are too small to be noticeable with the given vertical terminal size of just 600 pixels.
What is the full range of y-values in your complete data files?

In your example data, the changes are <0.01 in a y-scale of [0:10] with a vertical terminal size of 600 pixels. So, changes will hardly be visible.

In order to make extremely small changes visible you could plot for example the deviations from the mean values.

**Script:**

```
### plot deviations from mean value
reset session

$Data1 <<EOD
2023-10-13 08:05:22 3.77362878455463
2023-10-13 08:16:38 3.77371398500197
2023-10-13 08:27:54 3.77415538319968
2023-10-13 08:36:29 3.77337830143226
2023-10-13 08:46:20 3.7721485759286
EOD

$Data2 <<EOD
2023-10-13 08:06:12 9.58516483516484
2023-10-13 08:17:28 9.58519607843137
2023-10-13 08:28:44 9.5859382655561
2023-10-13 08:37:19 9.58436979727744
2023-10-13 08:47:09 9.58482994861757
EOD

stats $Data1 u 3 name "Data1" nooutput   # get the mean value
stats $Data2 u 3 name "Data2" nooutput

myTimeFmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M" timedate
set grid x,y
set key title "Deviations from\nmean value"
set xzeroaxis lw 1.5 lc "web-green"

plot $Data1 u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):($3-Data1_mean) w lp pt 7 lc "red"  ti sprintf("Data1: %.4f",Data1_mean), \
     $Data2 u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):($3-Data2_mean) w lp pt 7 lc "blue" ti sprintf("Data2: %.4f",Data2_mean)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:** (plotting to y1- and y2-axes)

**Script:**

```
### plot to y1- and y2-axis
reset session

$Data1 <<EOD
2023-10-13 08:05:22 3.77362878455463
2023-10-13 08:16:38 3.77371398500197
2023-10-13 08:27:54 3.77415538319968
2023-10-13 08:36:29 3.77337830143226
2023-10-13 08:46:20 3.7721485759286
EOD

$Data2 <<EOD
2023-10-13 08:06:12 9.58516483516484
2023-10-13 08:17:28 9.58519607843137
2023-10-13 08:28:44 9.5859382655561
2023-10-13 08:37:19 9.58436979727744
2023-10-13 08:47:09 9.58482994861757
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M" timedate
set ytics nomirror tc "red"
set y2tics tc "blue"

plot $Data1 u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):3 axes x1y1 w lp pt 7 lc "red"  ti "Data1", \
     $Data2 u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):3 axes x1y2 w lp pt 7 lc "blue" ti "Data2"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Theozh, if I plot two datasets that have values close together (e.g. means of  3.61951044356733 and 3.52317739850568) then the variations are successfully plotted.

I'll work on using your 'deviations from mean' example, thank you for illustrating it.

The '2 y axes' approach would work for the two datasets I posted, however this was in the interest of providing a minimal example - In the full system I'm working on there are around 100 data files with quite a wide range of data - that appear as horizontal lines.

Comment: @MattGumbley 100 datafiles in one graph might be pretty crowded (not sure how you want to make a legend), but this depends on the details. For 100 files, you better use a loop, but the implementation again depends on the details.